# Prove this limit for a general $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, proof-writing

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the following property: for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all $x$, 
$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \sin^2(\epsilon^2/9) + \epsilon \space \text{then} \space |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon$$
$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \epsilon^2 \space \text{then} \space |g(x) - 4| < \epsilon$$

Find a $\delta$ such that:
(iv) if $\displaystyle 0 < |x-2| < \delta \space \text{then} \space |\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$

This problem is from Spivak's calculus, so no wonder is it quite hard. Here is my attempt:

If $|f(x) - 2| < \min(1, \frac{2\epsilon}{5})$ and if $|\frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{4}| < \frac{\epsilon}{6}$ then $|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{2}| < \epsilon$

Then

$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \sin^2(\epsilon^2/9) + \epsilon \space \text{then} \space |f(x) - 2| < \epsilon$$

So $|f(x) - 2| < \min(1, \frac{2\epsilon}{5})$ if $|x - 2| < \sin^2(\frac{\min^2(1, \frac{2\epsilon}{5})}{9}) + \epsilon$

Then

$$ \text{if} \space 0 < |x - 2| < \epsilon^2 \space \text{then} \space |g(x) - 4| < \epsilon$$

first: If $|g(x) - 4| < \min(2, \frac{4\epsilon}{3})$ then $|\frac{1}{g(x)} - \frac{1}{4}| < \epsilon/6$

So $|x - 2| < \min^2(2, \frac{4\epsilon}{3})$

Let $\delta_1 = \sin^2(\frac{\min^2(1, \frac{2\epsilon}{5})}{9}) + \epsilon$

Let $\delta_2 = \min^2(2, \frac{4\epsilon}{3})$

Finally, $\displaystyle \delta = \min(\delta_1, \delta_2) = \min(\sin^2(\frac{\min^2(1, \frac{2\epsilon}{5})}{9}) + \epsilon, \text{min}^{2}(2, \frac{4\epsilon}{3}))$

$\space \space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\space
\blacksquare$